# Filter objects models depending on logged user

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have a form that contains a few fields, among these fields `project` that should be a `select` widget that contains projects that the logged user is member in. This is a portion of my code.

```
class PublicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super(PublicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user

    project = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=ProjectMembers.objects.filter(user__username=user),
        widget=forms.Select,
        required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'project', 'source']
```

I pass the logged user to the form in my view like this
`PublicationForm(request.POST, user=request.user)`
But I the form class I can't access the user variable, I tried
`...queryset=ProjectMembers.objects.filter(user__username=self.user)..`
`...queryset=ProjectMembers.objects.filter(user__username=user)..`
but I got these errors
`NameError: name 'self' is not defined`
and
`NameError: name 'user' is not defined`

Is there a solution or other method to filter projects that the logged user is a member is?

Answer (score 0):

Your `project` definition is done only once when the server is run, so it cannot depend on `self` or any other stuff. You have to distinguish class definition and instance creation. To make it dynamic, you have to remove it from class definition and set it inside `__init__`, so you can access `self` there.

```
def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
    super(PublicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.user = user
    self.fields['project'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(   
        queryset=ProjectMembers.objects.filter(                    
            user__username=self.user
        ),
        widget=forms.Select,
        required=False
    )
```

In this way, each instance of your form will get different `project` field.
Also, you may have to remove it from `fields` in `Meta` if you get errors like `field is not defined` or something like this.